# Can OpenStreetMaps do overlays in iOS like MKMapView?

Tags: mkmapview, openstreetmap

I want to write an application using openstreetmaps rather than mkmapview, but I'm not sure whether I can add an overlay onto the map. Does this functionality exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider http://cloudmade.com/ if you don't want to use MKMapView, or you can use OpenStreetMap data as tiles and use the TileMaps demo

Answer (score 0):

Overlays are basically another layer above maps, so you can reproduce it's behavior yourself.

There's an example from Craig Spitzkoff pre-annotation days you may want to look at: http://spitzkoff.com/craig/?p=108

Comment: There's also the route-me project that uses directly OpenStreetMaps.  https://github.com/route-me